# Nginx on Windows - can't bind any port

Tags: windows, bash, nginx

How to let nginx on windows bind the ports?

```
eska@DESKTOP-1NGBVMN:~$ sudo nginx;
sudo: nie udało się rozwiązać nazwy hosta DESKTOP-1NGBVMN
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:5555 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:5555 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:5555 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:5555 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:5555 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
eska@DESKTOP-1NGBVMN:~$
```

Comment: it seems that port 5555 is already being used by another process; you can check which process is using it with `lsof -i :5555`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the nginx or another process is already listening on that port. In order to determine what is listening on that port try this command:

```
sudo netstat -nltp
```

You can then free up the port by killing the corresponding process, where <PID> is the processID from the above command:

```
kill -TERM <PID>
```

Comment: it wasn't the problem. Restarting windows helped me with that, but i got another one. It's binding the port now, but something is blocking the connection. Any firewall or something. http://i.imgur.com/9lEcBnY.png

Comment: you need to edit your `hosts` file in windows `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and aim the domain name you've chosen for your virtual host in nginx to the localhost ip address.